# cctiddly change workspace URL

Tags: wiki, workspace, tiddlywiki

I'm using ccTiddly (using the TiddlyWiki) and I would like to change the URL of my workspaces. I am not sure how to proceed, I tried a first time and everything was corrupted.

The old URL is www.sub.mysite.com/wiki and the new one is www.mysite.com/wiki

I was thinking to move all the files from the FTP folder and then edit the database by removing the "sub" from all the URLs.

Will that work fine?

I only have 2 workspaces with few tiddlers each.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will depend which version of ccTiddly you are using.

Take a look at the fields in the database. I think you should be able to make the change just by updating the workspace field on the tiddler table but check there are no other fields storing the workspace.

When you said it corrupted everything last time, what exactly do you mean?

Comment: I will try that tonight thanks. Last time I wanted to change the name of the workspace so I (think) I changed it everywhere in the database but then it was saying "the worspace doesn't exist". I'm using ccTiddly 1.9.minimal

Comment: I moved everything in the new folder; exported the database, removed the "sub" and importer the DB again and it works fine! :)